# Prove parallelogram has four triangles with same area using vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

I need to prove that a parallelogram has four triangles with same area using vectors only. Thought to prove it using area of triangle and parallelogram but with no success. May you help me please? [image: See the figure here]

Comment: Which four triangles?  The figure only talks about two congruent triangles.

Comment: I would presume the four triangle divided by the two diagonals.

Comment: The area of $\triangle ADC$ is $\frac{1}{2}|c\times b|=\frac{1}{2}|(a+b)\times b|=\frac{1}{2}|a\times b+b\times b|$. Since $b\times b=0$ you get that this is equal to $\frac{1}{2}|a\times b|$, which is the area of $\triangle ABD$. As you see, all you need to use is that the cross product is linear on each of its components, and that it is alternating. This is $x\times y=-y\times x$. This has as a consequence that $x\times x=-x\times x$. So $2x\times x=0$, from where it follows that $x\times x=0$.

Comment: The area of a triangle is half base times height. Each of the triangles defined by the edges and one diagonal is bisected by the other diagonal. This can be put into vector form.

Comment: Hint: think of $X$ as the origin. (P.S. The question is very likely to be closed if you don't show more of your own work.)

Comment: Matthew Daly, yes - four triangle divided by the two diagonals.

Comment: conditionalMethod - great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $b$ be the vectors of two nonparallel sides of you parallelogram (as in your linked picture).  Now the diagonals of the parallelogram are given by $a+b$ and $a-b$.  The four triangles to think about are-up to translation-the triangles formed by the pairs $(a, \tfrac{1}{2}(a+b))$, $(b, \tfrac{1}{2}(a-b))$, $(a, \tfrac{1}{2}(a-b))$, and $(b, \tfrac{1}{2}(a+b))$.  Noting the following basic properties of the cross product for all vectors $u, v, w$ and scalars $c$, one completes the proof by four simple computations (which I'll leave to you):

1) $u \times u = 0$

2) $u \times (cv) = c (u \times v)$

3) $u \times (v + w) = (u \times v) + (u \times w)$

**Hint**: The common area is $\tfrac{1}{4}|a \times b|$.

Comment: You may need to prove that $X$ is the midpoint of $AC$ and $BD$

Comment: Ok! Sounds good!